# DataTable - make scrollable, set background colour and fix/freeze header row and first column

Tags: dart, flutter

I've started developing in Flutter with webview, charts, tables, but I met some problems with tables.

1. I use **DataTable** to represent data in a table.
   There is a first problem. By default, it isn't scrollable if data is out of a screen. So I embedded in some Widgets (i.e. SingleChildScrollView, ListView), but it was scrollable only in one direction (vertical or horizontal). I searched something about it and I found a plugin for both directions (*bidirectional_scroll_view 0.0.6*). After compilation I received an error

> Because app depends on bidirectional_scroll_view >=0.0.2 which
>   requires SDK version <2.1.0, version solving failed.

I'm using Dart SDK version: >=2.1.0 <3.0.0 in configuration.

Next, I found **PaginatedDataTable** which allows scrollable in both directions, but it is paginated table.
So anybody know is it possible to somehow scroll **DataTable** in both directions (vertical and horizontal)?

2. The second question (more important): is it possible to set background colour in header (first) row and first column in a table? Or even in any cell in a table?

For **DataColumn**/**DataCell** I tried embed Text in Container and then set Container colour, but the background colour was only set for text, the rest of a cell was with default colour.

i.e.

```
DataColumn(label: Container(child: Text('2011'), color: Colors.grey,)),
```

[image]

3. And is it possible to fixed/freeze header (first) row and first column. I mean the table is scrolled and first row/column is always visible on a screen. I couldn't find any solution ..

Answer (score 6):

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable()
        )
      ]
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
child: Center(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          DataTable()
        ],
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      )
  )
```