# error: The named parameter 'children' isn't defined, while using a ListView

Tags: list, view, dart, flutter

I am using Firebase realtime database to retrieve information and then present it in a scrollable DataTable.

To make the DataTable scrollable, I wrapped it up in a ListView, as per the comment of this post:
[DataTable - make scrollable, set background colour and fix/freeze header row and first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515578/datatable-make-scrollable-set-background-colour-and-fix-freeze-header-row-and)

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'cprdata.dart';
import 'dart:convert';


class CprAnalysis extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CPRState createState() => CPRState();
}

class CPRState extends State<CprAnalysis> {

  ///var cpr = UpdateData.getData();
  List<FilterData> acData;

  List<FilterData> getData() {
    var cpr = <FilterData>[];

    DatabaseReference cprData = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    cprData.reference().once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var d = snap.value;
      final jsonE = json.encode(d);
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonE);
      MyDataList zz = new MyDataList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
      zz.myList.forEach((data) {
        cpr.add(FilterData(sYMBOL: data.SYMBOL, fORECAST: data.FORECAST));
      }
      );
    },
    );
    print(cpr);
    return cpr;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    acData = getData();
  }

  Widget bodydata() => Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              ///shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              childern: <Widget>[
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: DataTable(
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text("Symbol"),
                      numeric: false,
                    ),
                    DataColumn(
                      label: Text("Forecast"),
                      numeric: false,
                    ),
                  ],

                  rows: acData.map((data) =>
                      DataRow(
                        cells: [
                          DataCell(
                            Text(data.sYMBOL),
                            showEditIcon: false,
                            placeholder: false,
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text(data.fORECAST),
                            showEditIcon: false,
                            placeholder: false,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                  )
                      .toList()
              ),
          ),
          ]
        ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("CPR Analysis"),
      ),
      body: Container(

        child: bodydata(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FilterData {
  String sYMBOL, fORECAST;

  FilterData({
    this.sYMBOL,
    this.fORECAST});
}
```

Expected output: Scrollable DataTable.

Actual output: error: The named parameter 'childern' isn't defined under ListView()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `children` as `childern` in your code.

Make your `ListView` code as -

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget> [
    //Your remaining code
  ]
),
```

Comment: OMG! I feel like an idiot now. Thank you very much.
My poor English did cost me.

Comment: No worries! Happens to the best of us. I'd be glad if you accept the answer :)

Comment: will do, it's not letting me, have to wait another 3 minutes.